# WooCommerce 'remove_action' not working in 'init' hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to modify the WooCommerce product filter plugin to add the filter as a `<div class="row">` instead of `"col-md-6"`.

In **functions.php**, I have removed the actions which hook into functions that create `col-md-6`, written new functions that create `row`s, and added actions that hook into my new functions. See code below.

```
function filter_styling()
{
    echo '<div class="row">';             
} 

function filter_styling2()
{
    echo '</div><div class="row">';            
}

function product_category_filter_changes()
{
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_main_content','oxy_before_breadcrumbs', 19);
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'oxy_after_breadcrumbs', 20);
    add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'filter_styling', 19);  
    add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'filter_styling2', 20);
}
add_action('init','product_category_filter_changes',10);
```

The add actions are registering, but not the remove actions. Any ideas?

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: The `init` hook may be too early to remove the action.

Comment: If that's the case, what would I do differently.....change the priority?

Comment: You can try changing `init` to `template_redirect`, and remove the priority...

Comment: that worked! thank you!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Removing an action can only be done when an action has already been added. Because of this, the `'init'` hook is likely too early.

I recommend using the `'template_redirect'` action hook, which will run after the plugins are loaded:

```
function product_category_filter_changes()
{
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_main_content','oxy_before_breadcrumbs', 19);
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'oxy_after_breadcrumbs', 20);
    add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'filter_styling', 19);  
    add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'filter_styling2', 20);
}
add_action('template_redirect','product_category_filter_changes');
```