# Wordpress remove_action within class

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to remove an action added by the Woocommerce Memberships plugin. Tracing back the actions contains functions it is initially added to the hook under

```
class WC_Memberships_Frontend {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array( $this, 'maybe_render_thank_you_content' ), 9 );
```

But this class is called by a private function and is a protected by the variable that its parent class declaration (as far as I can tell)

```
class WC_Memberships extends Framework\SV_WC_Plugin  {

    protected $frontend;

    private function frontend_includes() {
        // init shortcodes
        require_once( $this->get_plugin_path() . '/includes/class-wc-memberships-shortcodes.php' );

        \WC_Memberships_Shortcodes::initialize();

        // load front end
        $this->frontend = $this->load_class( '/includes/frontend/class-wc-memberships-frontend.php', 'WC_Memberships_Frontend' );
    }
```

I have search and tried a number of ways to remove this

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array( 'WC_Memberships', 'maybe_render_thank_you_content' ), 9 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array( 'WC_Memberships_Frontend', 'maybe_render_thank_you_content' ), 9 );
global $WC_Memberships;
remove_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array( $WC_Memberships, 'maybe_render_thank_you_content' ), 9 );
global $WC_Memberships_Frontend;
remove_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array( $WC_Memberships_Frontend, 'maybe_render_thank_you_content' ), 9 );
```

None of the above work, and other ways of trying to call `WC_Memberships()->frontend;` throw errors like 'Cannot access protected property WC_Memberships::$frontend'

Im not sure if the private function or protected variable are getting in the way, or if Im just not understanding something about removing an action within a class or nested classes but help would be **greatly** appreciated.

Edit:
Based on the [code found here](https://gist.github.com/bekarice/62cc848397fdedb02cfe) Ive tried

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array( wc_memberships()->get_frontend_instance(), 'maybe_render_thank_you_content', 9 ) );
```

but still no success.

Comment: Could be related ... see answer by rnevius
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122643/woocommerce-remove-action-not-working-in-init-hook

Comment: @Jamie_D I hadn't seen that, but testing a variety of methods tied to the template_redirect hook also didn't work.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to remove the actions within the class itself?

Comment: @Jamie_D No, I was just trying (unsuccessfully) to remove the class. Its not behaving like normal and in some googling looked like it was because it was added within a class. Currently I have added actions on either side to wrap it in a div and hide it with css, but would prefer to just remove it all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was trying to figure out how to match the `$this` in the original add_action `add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array( $this, 'maybe_render_thank_you_content' ), 9 );` to remove it.

I finally stumbled on [this chunk of code](https://gist.github.com/bekarice/62cc848397fdedb02cfe) which showed me how to reference the proper instance of the class.

Final working code:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array( wc_memberships()->get_frontend_instance(), 'maybe_render_thank_you_content', 9 ) );
```

Comment: great! This helped me. The point is, if you want to remove an action that was created by a class instance, you need to pass the instance again to remove the action, quite obvious, but I always used the static class, and that failed. Thanks for writing this down.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, it's usually not good practice to modify core or plugin files. Using a modification to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122643/woocommerce-remove-action-not-working-in-init-hook) , you could try adding to your themes functions.php file

```
function remove_aggravating_wcactions()
{
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'maybe_render_thank_you_content', 19 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'maybe_some_other_content', 20);
    ...
}
add_action('template_redirect','remove_aggravating_wcactions');
```

Comment: Yes, I have been working in the child themes function.php. And removing/adding other actions via this format works fine - Its this one particular function from the woo memberships plugin that I can't seem to modify. I was thought it may be the way it was originally declared using `array( $this, 'maybe_render_thank_you_content' )` rather than just the function name eg. `'maybe_render_thank_you_content'` - I thought it was referencing the class, and the class being protected I figured was my issue... my best guess anyway.